# Printing PDF with PDFBox never finishes

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I'm trying to print a file that I think is landscape mode (it measures 29,7 x 27 cm) but my program stops working when I submit the job.print(). Here's my code:

```
PDDocument documentAllegato = PDDocument.load(new File(percorsoDaStampare +"\\"+ fileInDaStampare[k].getName()));

System.out.println("oo");
job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(documentAllegato));
System.out.println("pp");
Attribute[] attributeArray2 = attributes.toArray();
for (Attribute a : attributeArray2) {
    //System.out.println(a.getName() + ": " + a);
}
System.out.println("qq");
Attribute copies2 = attributes.get(Copies.class);
Attribute media2 = attributes.get(Media.class);
Attribute mediaPrintableArea2 = attributes.get(MediaPrintableArea.class);
Attribute mediaTray2 = attributes.get(MediaTray.class);
Attribute orientationRequested2 = attributes.get(OrientationRequested.class);
Attribute sides2 = attributes.get(Sides.class);
System.out.println("rr");
attributes.remove(Sides.class);
attributes.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
//System.out.println("PRIMA DEL PRINT");
System.out.println("ss");

job.print();

System.out.println("tt");
documentAllegato.close();   //chiudo il documento
//System.out.println("Ho finito di stampare la copia cortesia");
System.out.println("uu");
//sposto la copia di cortesia in ARCHIVIATI
File dirArchiviati = new File(pathArchiviati);
File fileCortesiaDaArch= new File(""+fileInDaStampare[k]);
System.out.println("vv");
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(fileCortesiaDaArch, dirArchiviati);
//System.out.println("fileDaArch "+ fileCortesiaDaArch);
System.out.println("zz");
fileCortesiaDaArch.delete();
System.out.println("FINE ALLEGATO");
```

I tried to put it in portrait mode modifying some stuff but I couldn't get it. Any advice?

Comment: You mean 29,7 x 20,7 cm? A4 landscape.

Comment: Yes, I have this pdf on which pages are A4 landscape and my code stops working on "job.print()" line. I don't have errors when I print file in A4 portrait.

Comment: Myself I have no idea. Increase the memory with java -Xmx1g or such. Or call `documentAllegato.close();` before `job.print();`

Comment: I utilized the same function on other files and it works. The only difference is that the ones that have problems are pdf in landscape mode.

Comment: You seem to have neared the error. If no one had this error and comes with an answer, make minimal application. Landscape is nothing special, maybe more memory.

Comment: I checked: the file is blocked on spooling. How can I unblock it?

Comment: Sorry I am stumped for an answer/overasked.

Comment: Please tell what pdfbox version you are using and share the pdf file.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have pdfbox 2.0.13 . Here it is one of the files I can't print (they are all from the same source, it's an electricity bill) [link](https://ufile.io/mq9qg)

Comment: I'd like to keep this PDF as a "terrible example". Is this the bill of an existing person or is it test data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I waited over an hour for it to print... this is a known problem, discussed in [PDFBOX-3046](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3046) and also [here](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/05/avoid-transparency-when-printing-in-java/) and [here](https://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/very-slow-to-print-a-document-with-transparent-images-in-java/) and [here](https://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/slow-when-printing-a-page-that-has-a-watermark/) and [here](https://bfo.com/blog/2012/02/15/using_java_to_print_pdf_documents/): files with transparencies or with patterns take a long time to print. But yours breaks the record. The workaround is to pass a dpi value to `PDFPageable` which orders it to first render to an image and then print:

```
job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(documentAllegato, Orientation.AUTO, false, 300));
```

300 is the dpi value. The bigger this value, the bigger your spool files will be and the more memory will be used.

Comment: I don't know who you are, but you made my day! Thank you very much, now I can print and I've learned something useful!